# Couldn't insert fields in database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am a new to java web development. I am trying to develop a project. I got `SQLException` Error.

Here is my servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ocp2","root", "");
        ps=con.createStatement();
        RequestDispatcher rr;

        String courseid=req.getParameter("courseid");
        String coursename=req.getParameter("coursename");
        String s1=req.getParameter("sday");
        String s2=req.getParameter("smonth");
        String s3=req.getParameter("syear");
        String sdate=s1+'-'+s2+'-'+s3;
        String s4=req.getParameter("eday");
        String s5=req.getParameter("emonth");
        String s6=req.getParameter("eyear");
        String edate=s4+'-'+s5+'-'+s6;
        String duration=req.getParameter("duration");
        String fee=req.getParameter("fee");

        pw.println("insert into course values('"+courseid+"','"+coursename+"','"+sdate+"','"+edate+"','"+duration+"',"+fee+")");
        ps.executeUpdate("insert into course values('"+courseid+"','"+coursename+"','"+sdate+"','"+edate+"','"+duration+"',"+fee+")");
        con.commit();

        rr= req.getRequestDispatcher("incousuc.html");
        rr.forward(req,res);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        pw.println("exception"+e);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        pw.println("SQL EXCEPTION");    
        pw.println("TRY AGAIN");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        pw.println("can't load driver"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
</table>
</td>

<td width="75%" align="center">
    <h2>New Course Details</h2>
    <form name="facreg" onsubmit="return check()" action="./inscourse" method="post">
        <table width="500" height="30" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>courseid</center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="courseid" name="courseid" type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>coursename</center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="couname" name="couname" type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>StartingDate</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="sday" size="">
                        <option value=01>1</option>
                        <option value=02>2</option>
                        <option value=03>3</option>
                        <option value=04>4</option>
                        <option value=05>5</option>
                        <option value=06>6</option>
                        <option value=07>7</option>
                        <option value=08>8</option>
                        <option value=09>9</option>
                        <option value=10>10</option>
                        <option value=11>11</option>
                        <option value=12>12</option>
                        <option value=13>13</option>
                        <option value=14>14</option>
                        <option value=15>15</option>
                        <option value=16>16</option>
                        <option value=17>17</option>
                        <option value=18>18</option>
                        <option value=19>19</option>
                        <option value=20>20</option>
                        <option value=21>21</option>
                        <option value=22>22</option>
                        <option value=23>23</option>
                        <option value=24>24</option>
                        <option value=25>25</option>
                        <option value=26>26</option>
                        <option value=27>27</option>
                        <option value=28>28</option>
                        <option value=29>29</option>
                        <option value=30>30</option>
                        <option value=31>31</option>
                    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select name="smonth" size="">
                        <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
                        <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
                        <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
                        <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
                        <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
                        <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
                        <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
                        <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
                        <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
                        <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
                    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input id="syear" name="syear" type="text" size="8" maxlength="4" value="" onkeypress=checknumeric()>(yyyy)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EndingDate</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="eday" size="">
                        <option value=01>1</option>
                        <option value=02>2</option>
                        <option value=03>3</option>
                        <option value=04>4</option>
                        <option value=05>5</option>
                        <option value=06>6</option>
                        <option value=07>7</option>
                        <option value=08>8</option>
                        <option value=09>9</option>
                        <option value=10>10</option>
                        <option value=11>11</option>
                        <option value=12>12</option>
                        <option value=13>13</option>
                        <option value=14>14</option>
                        <option value=15>15</option>
                        <option value=16>16</option>
                        <option value=17>17</option>
                        <option value=18>18</option>
                        <option value=19>19</option>
                        <option value=20>20</option>
                        <option value=21>21</option>
                        <option value=22>22</option>
                        <option value=23>23</option>
                        <option value=24>24</option>
                        <option value=25>25</option>
                        <option value=26>26</option>
                        <option value=27>27</option>
                        <option value=28>28</option>
                        <option value=29>29</option>
                        <option value=30>30</option>
                        <option value=31>31</option>
                    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select name="emonth" size="">
                        <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
                        <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
                        <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
                        <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
                        <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
                        <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
                        <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
                        <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
                        <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
                        <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
                    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input id="eyear" name="eyear" type="text" size="8" maxlength="4" value="" onkeypress=checknumeric()>(yyyy)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>duration</center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="duration" name="duration" type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>Fee</center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="fee" name="fee" type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" value="" onkeypress="checknumeric()">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2>
                    <center>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                        <input name="reset" type="reset" value="RESET">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I run this code:
I got following error:

```
Jul 19, 2014 11:36:18 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load java.net.BindException.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1588)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createLinkFailureMessageBasedOnHeuristics(SQLError.java:1275)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException.<init>(CommunicationsException.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:1667)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4322)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.cleanup(ConnectionImpl.java:1348)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.finalize(ConnectionImpl.java:2679)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Jul 19, 2014 11:36:18 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
    INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load   com.mysql.jdbc.ProfilerEventHandlerFactory.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an  error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1588)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4346)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.cleanup(ConnectionImpl.java:1348)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.finalize(ConnectionImpl.java:2679)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And my database also not updated. 
Could anyone please tell me where i did i do mistake? and how can i solve it?

Comment: It shows SQLException.

Comment: Just SQLException is not useful, show us the message it shows.

Comment: Can you change the catch block of SQL Exception to read ```pw.println("SQL EXCEPTION "+e.getMessage()); ``` and post the result here?  This would help people to understand what the exception actually is.

Comment: I changed. Now it shows like this...                                INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.mysql.jdbc.ProfilerEventHandlerFactory.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: My wildest guess is that you are trying to set a string value to courseId.  The first value should not be surrounded by single quotes.

Same might be the problem with the last two fields in insert statement.

P.S: Don't just change the println line. Change the executeUpdate line too

Comment: @Vignesh try restarting your web application. and then post the exception message again (in your question itself, by editing it)

Comment: Try to run the query in mysql promp twhich you print, whether its inserting or not " insert into course values('112','null','01-Jan-2014','01-Jan-2015','12',45000) "

Comment: @vivek_ganesan I updated my question like you said. Could you please find out what mistake i have done?

Comment: @RajavelD Actually I tried to insert "insert into course values('112','java','01-Jan-2014','01-Jan-2015','12',45000)" this. But it will show like "insert into course values('112','null','01-Jan-2014','01-Jan-2015','12',45000)" this when i compile the code.

Comment: @PradeepSimha I have updated my error message in question. Could you please tell me what mistake i have done?

Answer (score 3):

your are getting null value of coursename you must change this line of servlet code

```
   String coursename=req.getParameter("coursename");
```

with this one

```
   String coursename=req.getParameter("couname");
```

check your html code you will get reason

Comment: Please stop posting thrice on the same question, instead __edit the answer__ likewise, for any new update that you come out with :-) +1 though, to this answer, seems like that is on target.

Comment: @nIcEcOw thanks for +1 and i will take care of it in future